# How do I fix this grep command?

Tags: bash

This `grep` command is not doing the `if` statement for some reason.

```
 #!/bin/bash

ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
if airbase-ng -c 6  -e "Steve's HotSpot" wlan0   | grep -q  " Client"
then
clear
echo "SomeOne connected to your Hotspot"
fi
```

Comment: What does the output of `airbase-ng -c 6  -e "Steve's HotSpot" wlan0` look like ?

Comment: 03:14:42  Created tap interface at0
03:14:42  Trying to set MTU on at0 to 1500
03:14:42  Access Point with BSSID 1E:AB:15:29:8F:14 started.

Comment: @Mohamed: If that is the output, then why would you expect `grep -q "Client"` to indicate success (and thus enter the `if` clause), given that the output doesn't contain `"Client"`? Generally, please add sample/expected input/output to the _question_ - not to comments - and preferably _to begin with_.

Comment: It Will contain and output of Client when someone connects to it

Comment: @Mohamed: Add an _actual instance_ of an input string that _does_ contain `" Client"` to your question, so others can verify the problem. One hypothetical reason for the `grep` command not working would be if `airbase-ng` printed to _stderr_ - but then you'd see the output on the terminal.

Comment: @Mohamed: Also, your shebang line, as printed in the question, contains a space at the start - this would cause it to be ignored, and what shell would process the file would depend on the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

*Untested Code*

```
if [[ -n $(airbase-ng -c 6  -e "Steve's HotSpot" wlan0   | grep -q  " Client") ]]
```

The `-n`says that the if conditional is a non-zero while the `$()` executes the command in its own shell to push the output back to the script.

[Bash Programming Help](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't (fix grep).

Note that your code is testing the exit value of grep, not the text string produced.

What you could do is assign the results of the command you use to one or two variables, and then test the correct variable. That also allows you to echo the variable to see what is going on:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
result="$(airbase-ng -c 6  -e "Steve's HotSpot" wlan0   | grep "Client")"
exitval="$?"
echo "the var is $result"
if [[ $exitval == 0 ]]
then
    clear
    echo "SomeOne connected to your Hotspot"
fi
```

If you really need to test the string output from grep, then change:

```sh
if [[ $exitval == 0 ]]
```

to

```sh
if [[ -n $result ]]
```

Comment: Considering grep's output is supressed with `-q`, I  really wonder what your or ioneyed "solution" gains

Comment: Syntax Error of lines 16 and 18

Comment: @Mohamed Considering that there are only 13 lines in the code inside the gray area. I shall assume that you copied something that should not be used in a script.